# SQL Function translates HTML to simple HTML

Tags: t-sql

I'm working with WinForms and I'm using RichTextBox to be able to use bold and italic.
When I insert into the DB I import it as HTML to be able to export them back as HTML later and to get the same font.

While trying to print a report I used the HTMLTextBox, but it seems that the control only admits simple markup language and will crash if used the HTML I'm getting.

So in order to complete my work, I set a non-adjustable fonts and only allowed him to use normal font, bold, or italic, that way the CSS Class will remain the same whenever he used the desired fonts.

I tried to set up a function that simplifies the HTML to be able to translate the HTML in order to be admitted in the HTMLTextBox.

I used this function but it's not working and I've been working on it for 2 days and I'm new to SQL.

```
DECLARE @HTMLpure nvarchar(max)  ='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Untitled</title><style type="text/css">  .p_CC664AAA { margin: 0px 0px 12px 0px;text-align: left;text-indent: 0pt;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; }   .s_E5E150E4 { font-family: ''Calibri'';font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;color: #000000; }   .s_6BF1D20F { font-family: ''Calibri'';font-style: normal;font-size: 16px;color: #000000; }   .s_F152B3A2 { font-family: ''Calibri'';font-style: italic;font-size: 16px;color: #000000; }   .s_40C97128 { font-family: ''Calibri'';font-style: normal;font-size: 16px;color: #000000;text-decoration: underline; }   </style></head><body><p class="p_CC664AAA"><span class="s_E5E150E4">BOLD</span><span class="s_6BF1D20F"> </span><span class="s_F152B3A2">iTALIC </span><span class="s_40C97128">UNDERLINE </span><span class="s_6BF1D20F">NORMAL</span></p></body></html>'
DECLARE @FinalHTML nvarchar(max)= ''
DECLARE @newHTMLpure nvarchar(max)

SET @HTMLpure = REPLACE (@HTMLpure, '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Untitled</title><style type="text/css">' , '')
set @HTMLpure = replace (@HTMLpure, '.p_CC664AAA { margin: 0px 0px 12px 0px;text-align: left;text-indent: 0pt;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; } ','')
set @HTMLpure = replace (@HTMLpure, '.s_E5E150E4 { font-family: ''Calibri'';font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;color: #000000; }','')
set @HTMLpure = replace (@HTMLpure , '.s_40C97128 { font-family: ''Calibri'';font-style: normal;font-size: 16px;color: #000000;text-decoration: underline; } ','')
set @HTMLpure = replace (@HTMLpure , '.s_6BF1D20F { font-family: ''Calibri'';font-style: normal;font-size: 16px;color: #000000; } ','')
set @HTMLpure = replace (@HTMLpure , '.s_F152B3A2 { font-family: ''Calibri'';font-style: italic;font-size: 16px;color: #000000; } ','')
set @HTMLpure = REPLACE (@HTMLpure , '.p_384D933F { margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;text-align: left;text-indent: 0pt;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; }' , '')
set @HTMLpure = replace (@HTMLpure ,'</style></head><body><p class="p_CC664AAA">','')
set @HTMLpure = REPLACE (@HTMLpure ,'</style></head><body><p class="p_384D933F">' , '')
set @HTMLpure = replace (@HTMLpure ,'</p></body></html>','')

WHILE len(LTRIM(@HTMLpure)) > 0
BEGIN
   IF LTRIM(@HTMLpure) like  '<span class="s_E5E150E4">%'
   BEGIN
     SET @HTMLpure = replace (LTRIM(@HTMLpure) ,'<span class="s_E5E150E4">','<strong>')
     SET @HTMLpure=Stuff(@HTMLpure, CharIndex('</span>', @HTMLpure), Len('</span>'), '</strong>')
     SELECT @newHTMLpure = substring(LTRIM(@HTMLpure),charindex('<strong>',LTRIM(@HTMLpure))+len('<strong>'),charindex('</strong>',LTRIM(@HTMLpure))-charindex('<strong>',LTRIM(@HTMLpure))-len('<strong>'))
     SET @HTMLpure = REPLACE(@HTMLpure,'<strong>' + @newHTMLpure + '</strong>','')
     SET @newHTMLpure = '<strong>' + @newHTMLpure + '</strong>'
     SET @FinalHTML = @newHTMLpure
     SET @newHTMLpure = ''
    END

    ELSE IF LTRIM(@HTMLpure) like '<span class="s_F152B3A2">%'
    BEGIN
     SET @HTMLpure = replace (LTRIM(@HTMLpure) ,'<span class="s_F152B3A2">','<em>')
     SET @HTMLpure=Stuff(LTRIM(@HTMLpure), CharIndex('</span>', LTRIM(@HTMLpure)), Len('</span>'), '</em>')
     SELECT @newHTMLpure = substring(LTRIM(@HTMLpure),charindex('<em>',LTRIM(@HTMLpure))+len('<em>'),charindex('</em>',LTRIM(@HTMLpure))-charindex('<em>',LTRIM(@HTMLpure))-len('<em>'))
     SET @HTMLpure = REPLACE(LTRIM(@HTMLpure),'<em>' + @newHTMLpure + '</em>','')
     SET @newHTMLpure = '<em>' + @newHTMLpure + '</em>'
     SET @FinalHTML = @FinalHTML + @newHTMLpure
     SET @newHTMLpure = ''
   END
   ELSE IF LTRIM(@HTMLpure) like '<span class="s_40C97128">%'
   BEGIN
     SET @HTMLpure = replace (@HTMLpure ,'<span class="s_40C97128">','<u>')
     SET @HTMLpure=Stuff(@HTMLpure, CharIndex('</span>', @HTMLpure), Len('</span>'), '</u>')
     SELECT @newHTMLpure = substring(@HTMLpure,charindex('<u>',@HTMLpure)+len('<u>'),charindex('</u>',@HTMLpure)-charindex('<u>',@HTMLpure)-len('<u>'))
     SET @HTMLpure = REPLACE(@HTMLpure,'<u>' + @newHTMLpure + '</u>','')
     SET @newHTMLpure = '<u>' + @newHTMLpure + '</u>'
     SET @FinalHTML = @FinalHTML + @newHTMLpure
     SET @newHTMLpure = ''
    END
    ELSE IF LTRIM(@HTMLpure) like '<span class="s_6BF1D20F">%'
    BEGIN
     SET @HTMLpure=Stuff(LTRIM(@HTMLpure), CharIndex('<span class="s_6BF1D20F">', LTRIM(@HTMLpure)), Len('<span class="s_6BF1D20F">'), ' ')
     SET @HTMLpure=Stuff(LTRIM(@HTMLpure), CharIndex('</span>', LTRIM(@HTMLpure)), Len('</span>'), ' ')
     SET @HTMLpure = REPLACE(LTRIM(@HTMLpure),'' + @newHTMLpure + '','')    
     SELECT @newHTMLpure = substring(LTRIM(@HTMLpure),charindex(' ',LTRIM(@HTMLpure))+len(' '),charindex(' ',LTRIM(@HTMLpure))-charindex('% ',LTRIM(@HTMLpure))-len(' '))\
     IF @newHTMLpure = '' 
     BEGIN
    SET @newHTMLpure = '&NBSP;'
     END
            SET @FinalHTML  = @FinalHTML +  @newHTMLpure
        SET @newHTMLpure = ''
     END
            SET @FinalHTML = @FinalHTML + ' ' + @newHTMLpure
         END
            SET @HTMLpure = @FinalHTML
         END
```

I'm really sorry for this long code and I know I should have used vb coding instead of SQL but I'm taking it as a practice for me in SQL

Please help,

Thank you.

Comment: That's really ugly, and remind me again *why* we're doing this in SQL?

Comment: And what does "not working" mean?

Comment: I'm not really good at SQL as you can see and by not working is that there's an infinite loop somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Okay a few things here.

1. Store the most abstract version of your data in your database. I.e. if you need to store information about the typesetting of text you need attributes such as `face`, `size`, `is_bold`, &c.  This will allow your data to be applicable to all possible situations (you should be more likely to change your frontend than your data schema)
2. Logic for rendering data should be separate from that data. When you extract text with it's associated attributes (`face`...) the rendering into `HTML`, or **any other presentation format** such as whatever your `TextBox` expects, should be done as close to the point of presentation as possible.

Code related to presentation goes in your GUI.

Data goes in your database.